# Order processing error in PayPal pro for Xcart 4 website

Tags: paypal, x-cart

I am working on a Xcart online store. Its version is 4. For payment gateway we have integrated "PayPal Pro" but its showing following error When I check out through paypal payment pro with my credit card:

**Order declined.
Review your data or contact the store administrator. 
Reason: Declined Error: (Code: , Severity: )**

So please suggest me for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have fixed this issue. We found that there was issue in Payment file which was sending details to PayPal. Tried with a test user and enabled "Pro" on the test sandbox account. After that it started working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add this code

```
define('PAYPAL_ADVANCED_DEBUG', 1);
define('PAYPAL_DEBUG', 1);
define('PAYPAL_STANDARD_DEBUG', 1)
```

to your config.local.php (create if not exists)

2)Then check var/log/x-errors_paypal-* logs

3)Remove the debug code

Comment: This is working fine if we are testing it on local. But when trying to check on live site then its not working. There is module available for PayPal and not sure where to write this code ?